# How to access apache from any IP on the network?

Tags: apache, networking, ip, server

My 3 Windows computers have the following network IPs:

*Computer 1 IP: 192.168.100.1 
*Computer 2 IP: 192.168.100.2 
*Apache Computer 3 IP: 192.168.100.3 (this computer is running Apache )

I can access apache from the same apache hosting computer by writting http://localhost in the firefox browser

I can access Apache server by writing the IP: 192.168.100.3 on the browser of any of the 2 computers above.

I can change the IP Address of apache hosting computer 3 into anything that follows the format 192.168.100.XXX.XXX and get it to work in all the other 2 computers with the listed IPs.
When I change the IP of the computer running the Apache server into something like XXX.XXX.100.3, I can't access it from the 3 computers above...

I am going to use the Apache server in my workplace and I don't want to mix it with network IPs. Any workaround to the problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the apache http server, it is a general network issue you see here. The full answer depends on your local network topology, especially the network mask you use. Since you did not post that an answer cannot be complete here. But as a general hint I hope this helps:

To be able to contact another system a computer sends a package to the destiny address. Typically that address is routed between networks. At home this is typically done by some network router you get from your broadband service company or similar. 
The router needs to decide where to send the package to. He does so based on the destiny IP address in the package and by comparing that to routing entries (routes) that define, which network to reach how. So which range of IP addresses to reach how.

In your setup you *probably* have the network 190.100.100.0 defined as your local network (strictly speaking this is invalid, but it will work for you). 190.100.110.4 is not inside this network. So your router will assume that the address is *outside* your local network and send the package out into the internet! Or it will simply be discarded, if no route to the outside world exists.

So to be able to reach that server by its modified IP address you'd have to modify the routing entries inside your network router.

Comment: Hi arkascha and thanks very much for your reply. The same problem happens if I use a simple 4-ports switch to connect the 4 computers. So there is no router to route anything here.....

Comment: Are the packages sent out at all then? I mean if your local systems know (from their own network settings) that the target IP is not inside the local network, and there is no route defined in their local network settings leading out of the network, then maybe the packages are dropped? What happens if you fire a request? Do you run into a timeout or do you get an error immediately? In case of an immediate error the packages are dropped silently, if you run into a timeout then it might make sense to use a network sniffer on the target system to see if the packages actually exist on the network.

Comment: Oh, and make really sure that the http server really listens on all addresses, not only on the single old one. And reset the switch / deplug it for more than 20 secs. Also make sure the error is not cached locally, so clear your browser caches or make a deep reload instead of a simple reload.

Comment: It is probably is a good diea if you a add your network settings of the local systems to the question above as mentioned before. Without such information this is like a guessing game. Not much fun.

Comment: Sure, something like this is to be expected. As written above: this is a question of your local network settings. I suggested you post those settings. Especially the network mask configured in your systems.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to access an address on a subnet different than the host from which you are originating, the host will send the traffic to its configured gateway (router) address.  The router must have a specific route to the destination subnet, else it sends it to the default (normally the Internet) route.

You can't connect between different subnets without a router routing the traffic between the networks.  This is Networking 101.

Answer (score 0):

I will mark your reply as accepted. The IP addresses I provided were misleading and invalid like you noticed and I edited them (yes they are local private network addresses). Before I let you do a final comment and mark your reply as accepted I would like to add the following for our reference.  Private networks can use IP addresses anywhere in the following ranges:

```
192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255 (65,536 IP addresses)
172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255 (1,048,576 IP addresses)
10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255 (16,777,216 IP addresses)
```

Now probably windows validates the above addresses and won't let you use any ranges beyond the above even if you simply hub your local network on a switch without a router.